# How to find the path of the file calling require?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, minitest

I have a large `test_helper` file which includes code for unit and integration test. I would like to split it into two, without having to change every `require "test_helper"`.

To accomplish that, I want to conditionally call `unit_test_helper` or `integration_test_helper` based on the file path of the test file calling `require "test_helper"`.

How can I find the path of the file calling `require "test_helper"`?

Comment: You can't do it like that. When you tell Rails to run your tests it calls `load` on each test. That means any required file is only loaded once for the whole test run. So whatever conditional code you would put into `test_helper` will only be executed once for the whole test run.

Comment: Just make `test_helper` require the two other files.